# Yield items without request in Scrapy spider

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I want a Scrapy spider to yield an item without making a request first. I need the following functionality, but without the request to example.com.

```py
class TestSpider:
    name = "test"

    def __init__(self, item, *args, **kwargs):
        self.item = item

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request('https://example.com/', callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        yield self.item
```

I tried yielding the item directly from `start_requests`, but the Scrapy [expects it to return](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests) an iterable of `scrapy.Request` objects.

Yielding directly from the constructor of course also does not work, because constructors have to return `None`.

Comment: Is it an item that you want to return without scraping any webpage or any start request?

Comment: Looks like a bug in Scrapy. I can confirm that it tries to process the very first `yield` as a `scrapy.Request`

Comment: I don’t think it is possible at the moment with Scrapy. Could you ellaborate on the reasons why those items cannot be yield after the initial request?